# An extra one? Who knows

Tags: visual

Each of the 5 images at the bottom of this picture represent a single word. And the answer to this puzzle is a six letter word. Try to somehow make sense out of it!

---

[image]

---

Hint

> word length of each of the five images from top to bottom;
>  5, 5, 5, 5, 7(gerund)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part:

> Try to overlap the "lines" with the grid in the center, then observe the cells which are not covered by the lines!

We will get:

> The letters! Also do you notice the labels are "half" of some shapes i.e.
>
>  - Half circle: **T**
>  - Half pentagon: **T**
>  - Half rhombus: **H**
>  - Half square: **S**
>  - Half triangle: **M**

After that, for the second part:

> It is simply a rebus i.e.
>
>  - Half pentagon: **COUCH**
>  - Half circle: **WASTE**
>  - Half triangle: **SHELL**
>  - Half square: **LIGHT**
>  - Half rhombus: **TEARING**

And combining them:

> If we match both halves, and replace the x-th letter by its first part where x is denoted on the right side of the rebus, we will have:
>
>  **TOUCH, TASTE, SMELL, SIGHT, HEARING**
>
>  Thus the final answer for this puzzle is our five **SENSES**! (Or do you believe in sixth sense?)

Comment: Nice! Perhaps you should make it clearer what the six letter word is.

Comment: @athin Well done :)

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't realize the final answer should be a six-letter word ><